# No method Error Undefined method for stringify_keys for array for my time-sheet controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here, a user submits a timesheet for some time period by selecting  start-date and end-date. Those  params  are assigned to timesheet_params  then it is passed to the timesheet model.

I am getting this error when building timesheets for particular days:

> Started GET
>   "/users/2/timesheets/build?start_date=06/08/2013&end_date=06/11/2013"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jun 11 23:24:23 +0530 2013 Processing by
>   TimesheetsController#build as */*   Parameters:
>   {"end_date"=>"06/11/2013", "start_date"=>"06/08/2013", "user_id"=>"2"}
>   [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE
>   `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for
>    #<Array:0xb23ed8f4>):app/controllers/timesheets_controller.rb:23:in`new'   app/controllers/timesheets_controller.rb:23:in `build'

The code I am using is:

```
// time sheet  build method //
def build
    @user = current_user
    timesheet_params = params.select{|k,v| ["start_date", "end_date", "user_id"].include?(k) }
    @timesheet = Timesheet.new(timesheet_params)
    @timesheet.placement = @user.active_assignment

    if @timesheet.valid?
      if @timesheet.timesheet_days.blank?
        build_timesheet_days
      end
    else
      render :status => 500 and return
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's look like timesheet_params is Array and Timesheet.new is asking for a Hash

Comment: @tlewin: Which will happen with Ruby 1.8 but not 1.9+

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you're using Ruby 1.8 where [`Hash#select` returns an Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select):

> **select {|key, value| block} => array**
>
> Returns a new array consisting of `[key,value]` pairs for which the block returns `true`.

That would mean that your `timesheet_params` is actually an Array. Then you hand that Array to ActiveRecord:

```
Timesheet.new(timesheet_params)
```

and AR will try to convert the what-it-expects-to-be-a-Hash keys to strings using the [`stringify_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys) method that Rails patches into Hash and everything falls apart because `timesheet_params` is actually an Array. That at least matches the behavior you're seeing.

The solution is to not use `params.select` at all, just use the [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method that Rails adds to Hash:

```
timesheet_params = params.slice("start_date", "end_date", "user_id")
```

The `Hash#select` method in newer versions of Ruby return a Hash. Also 1.8 is quite ancient so you should upgrade ASAP if possible.

---

**For the pedants**: Yes, `params` is actually an [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) but that subclasses Hash and is rarely an important distinction.